# Why does the "typeof" of a named function expression return undefined?

Tags: javascript, hoisting, function-expression

I'm new to JS, so please forgive me if this sounds stupid. I was playing with the concepts of **function declaration** and **function expression**.

I have the following code:

```js
var printSomething = function printSomeString(string) {
  console.log(string);
}

console.log(typeof printSomething); // function
console.log(typeof printSomeString); // undefined
```

If I go by the definition of `hoisting` in JavaScript, by the time I use `printSomething` and `printSomeString`, they should be available since their declarations have been hoisted.

`typeof printSomething`  returns function, but `typeof printSomeString` returns undefined. Why so?

Isn't this named function expression already declared and hoisted before being used?

Isn't a named function expression itself a function?

Also, when I call `printSomeString('Some STRING')`, it returns the following

> Uncaught ReferenceError: printSomeString is not defined

What is going on here?

Comment: `printSomeString` only exists in its own scope, if I may: https://jsfiddle.net/vqL2814y/

Answer (score 1):

`printSomeString` is a not a global variable its local variable to the another function `printSomething`. Try using `console.log()` inside it.

```js
var printSomething = function printSomeString(string) {
  console.log(typeof printSomeString)
}

console.log(typeof printSomething); // function
printSomething()
```